# Execute Kusto query present in the Table result

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-sentinel

I have a table that has many other columns such as username, hostname, etc. One of the columns also stores a certain Query.

UserQueryTable

| Username | Hostname | CustomQuery |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | xyz | some_query_1 |
| David | abc | some_query_2 |
| Rock | mno | some_query_3 |
| Well | stu | some_query_4 |

When I run a kql such as :

```
UserQueryTable | where Username == "Sam"
```

I get:

| Username | Hostname | CustomQuery |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | xyz | **some_query_1** |

Note the "**some_query_1**" value under **CustomQuery**? That is an actual KQL query that is also part of the table result. I want to find a way where I can **retrieve the "some_query_1" and EXECUTE it** right after my KQL "UserQueryTable | where Username == "Sam""

That CustomQuery query will give me additional info about my alert and I need to get that Query string from the table and execute it.
The **CustomQuery** in the table looks something like this

```
let alertedEvent = datatable(compressedRec: string)
[' -----redacted----7ziphQG4Di05dfsdfdsgdgS6uThq4H5fclBccCH6wW8M//sdfgty==']
| extend raw = todynamic(zlib_decompress_from_base64_string(compressedRec)) | evaluate bag_unpack(raw) | project-away compressedRec;
alertedEvent
```

So basically the 1st Query returns a result where one of the returned column itself contains Queries and I want to be able to run the returned Queries.
The **Query_** == **CustomQuery**
[image: the Query_ here is the CustomQuery]

I tried using the User-defined functions but have not been able to come up with something that works. Please help!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you give a full example of the input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, for security reasons, you can't do that.

To accomplish what you want you would need to write a client app that get the results of the first query and the runs the second ones.

For reference you can't even reference table names "dynamically" on KQL.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a query that returns a list of queries and would like to get as a result a list of queries out of this set that was actually run.

In that case, you can:

1. Use `.show queries` command which returns the list of queries that was executed on your cluster(read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/queries#show-queries)). Notice `.show queries` would return the list of queries you ran, or - if you have database admin permissions - the list of queries anyone ran on the database.
2. Enable diagnostic settings on your cluster, and send Query logs (read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/using-diagnostic-logs?tabs=ingestion#enable-diagnostic-logs)). This would send all queries that were executed on your cluster to a log analytics workspace of your choosing.

You can then use either of these options and join with your table to figure out which queries were actually executed. For instance, using the first option:

```
.show queries | join datatable (Query_: string)
        [
            "Table | where somecol contains 1",
            "Table | where somecol contains 2"
        ] on $left.Text == $right.Query_
```

Comment: Avnera, Ravit, thank you for your comments. I have edited the Question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution than running the query, you can extract the compressed text with a regex and decompress in the same line

```
Table
| extend Compressed = extract(@"\['([^;]+)']",1,<CompressedTextQuery>)
| extend raw = todynamic(zlib_decompress_from_base64_string(Compressed))
```